# Finding subgroups of a group

Tags: group-theory

Find all the subgroups of $A_{4} = \lbrace\sigma \in S_{4}: sgn{(\sigma)} = +1\rbrace$.

$|A_{4}| = 12$ so by Lagrange's theorem, we may have subgroups of orders 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 or 12.

We have the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$ (of order 1) and $A_{4}$ (of order 12).

order 2: since 2 is prime, we have cyclic subgroups generated by elements of order 2:
$\left< (1 2)(3 4)\right>$, $\left< (1 3)(2 4)\right>$ and $\left< (1 4)(2 3)\right>$

order 3: also prime, so cyclic subgroups generated by elements of order 3:
$\left< (1 2 3)\right>$, $\left< (1 2 4)\right>$, $\left< (1 3 4)\right>$ and $\left< (2 3 4)\right>$.

How do I find subgroups with non-prime order, (ie. non-cyclic subgroups)? If there are none, how do I prove such?

Comment: Oh wow, that was supremely stupid of me @DietrichBurde.  Sorry, wasn't thinking.

Comment: never mind ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse of Lagrange does not hold in general, and $A_4$ is a standard example  here: it has no subgroup of order $6$. For a proof see any exercise collection on Lagrange's theorem. We have done the divisors $1,2,3,6,12$, so what is left is to find the subgroups of order $4$. We have the following proper *normal* subgroup
$$
\{ id, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}
$$
which is the Klein $4$-group. This is the only possibility since $A_4$ has no elements of order $4$, so that we can only use elements of order $1$ and $2$.